# External HD not mouting - Actual VCN different from expected VCN

Tags: mount, backup, external-hdd

My workstation is Ubuntu 17.10. I use an external HD for backup. Today I was testing a new backup tool that made changes from the original backup folder "/media/rainer/Rainer Backup" to "/media/rainer/Rainer Backup2".

Now, when I try to access the drive with Nautilus, I am getting the following error message:

[image]

I have tried

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media
```

Anyone has an idea of how to recover the drive?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after after all: running

```
    chkdsk F:/f
```

in the terminal of a Windows 10 machine (where F is the name of the drive) fixed the external HD.